# Stop tooltip span from wrapping at each word in CSS

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have created tooltips that appear when certain links have hovered over. The tooltips are spans with the class `tooltiptext`, and the links use the id `gloss`.

The problem is that the tooltips end up being the width of the longest word inside them. I've tried setting a minimum width, but it's impractical because some of the tooltips are only a few words, whilst others are whole paragraphs. I don't want all of the text to be on the same line if there's a paragraph of text, so `white-space: nowrap` is impractical too.

Any ideas?

```css
#gloss {
  border-bottom: solid 1pt blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#gloss:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align:center; background-color:#8899ff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#gloss:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br>
<!--<br>s to move the paragraph down-->
<p>This is some text, with a <a href="#" id="gloss">link<span class="tooltiptext">Here is some information about the link.</span></a>. And the text continues.</p>
```

Comment: Can I see your blueprint?

Comment: I posted code with the question. What else do you need to see?

Comment: I just want the picture to see what you want to make.

Comment: You've got this problem because the word link is too short. If you use a longer text in your "a" the tooltip will be wider.  
There's no perfect solution here, since your span is within the a, "width: 100%" is 100% of its parent for it, so you'll have to put some min-width or height manually.

Comment: @Flinth that makes sense. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Would there be a way of placing the span outside of the anchor tag, but still targeting it with CSS, or would that require Javascript?

Comment: You can target it, but you won't be able to place it above the link if it's outside. Putting the "a" and the "span" in a wrapper shouldn't improves the situation either, since the wrapper will still have the size of the link text. JS seems like the only option unless there's some trickery using exotic CSS statements I don't know :-)

Answer (score 0):

add `style="width: auto;"` in to your span tag it will work

```
<br><br><br><br><br>
<!--<br>s to move the paragraph down-->
<p>This is some text, with a <a href="#" id="gloss">link<span style="width: auto;" class="tooltiptext">Here is some information about the link</span></a>. And the text continues.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding 'width:auto;' makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved similar problem like below.

```
.tooltiptext {
    max-inline-size: 600px; //or whatever you want there
    width: max-content;
    white-space: normal;
}
```